# I wanted to pass an array from xcode to local html

Tags: iphone, html, arrays, uiwebview

I am using NSMutable array containing muliple objects and I know how to locate and load local HTML in Webview using loadHTMLstring.
Just wanna know how can I pass array to HTML.

Very confused.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is in the array?

Comment: Basically I am fetching data from Sap backend and have imported through SUP in array . In array data is firefox,Chrome,IE,Netscape..

Comment: Ummm... the question that dasdom had, which I think is a good question, is if you do `NSLog(@"contents of array is %@", [yourMutableArray description]);`, what would appear in the console log?  If it's simply NSString objects, you're all set... if it's some crazy abstract type or JSON or XML or whatever, then you have some more work to do.

Comment: Micheal its just an NSString objects and I cant use stringByreplacingoccurenceofstring while loading in HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your array as a JSON string to JavaScript inside the loaded page by calling UIWebView `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:`.

First, use a JSON library to encode the contents of your array into a JSON-encoded string.  If you use [SBJSON](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) then something like this:

```
NSString* json = [myArray JSONRepresentation];
```

(this will work with your simple array of strings.  If you have a more complicated array of other objects, they will have to be compatible with the JSON serializer)

Then, pass this to your webview:

```
NSString* js = [NSString stringWithFormat: "myJavaScriptFunction( '%@' );", json];
[myWebView stringByEvealuatingJavascriptFromString: js];
```

In your HTML file you will have to implement a JavaScript function (in this example, "myJavaScriptFunction") that accepts the passed JSON, and decodes it into a Javascript array.

Comment: Hi Tom, Had tried your method but no success,m writing my code kindly suggest if any modifications.

Comment: Had tried your method but didnt work.Could you suggest something from my code: SBJsonWriter *js = [SBJsonWriter new];
pie_arr1 = [SBJsonWriter new];
NSString *json = [js stringWithObject:self.pie_arr1];
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]; NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:NULL];NSString *java=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"javafunction('%@');",json];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:java];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:baseURL];

Comment: I really cant look at that and determine anything.  My suggestion to you is to use the debugger to inspect what's happening each step of the way.  Is the JSON what you expect?  Does it arrive in the html page (use an alert() or something...) etc.

Comment: m able to generate JSON but since m using loadHTMLstring with baseURL to load local HTML and included .js plugins(in my HTML),m not able to load my webview again with stringByevaluatingjavascriptfromstring that means unable to pass my array to javascript.The code is :                          'NSString *java=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"javafunction('%@');",json];'     [webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:baseURL];    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:java];  and in my HTML m using    function javafunction(inp)    {var arr=newArray();    arr='inp';    alert(arr[0]);}